# TensorFlow function to check whether a value is in given range?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I know there is `tf.greater(x,y)` which will return true if x > y (element-wise). Is there a function that returns true if lower_bound < x < upper_bound (element-wise) for a tensor x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not a specific function for that, but you can use a combination of `tf.greater`, `tf.less`, and `tf.logical_and` to get the same result.

```
lower_tensor = tf.greater(x, lower)
upper_tensor = tf.less(x, upper)
in_range = tf.logical_and(lower_tensor, upper_tensor)
```

Comment: Why not simply use [tf.range](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/range) instead?

Comment: @Hagbard `tf.range` doesn't return a Tensor of type `bool`, which is what the original question is asking for.